# How to get data-id in jstree JSON data

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am trying to get `data-id` from a tree form generated with a JsTree (checkbox form) but it's not working. I am using `$.each()`, because you can check more checkboxes. This is how my script looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-save-button").on('click', function(){
        let boxes = check_checkboxes();
        alert(JSON.stringify(boxes));

    });

    function check_checkboxes(){
        let boxes_id = [];
        let boxes = $(".js-categories-checkboxtree").jstree("get_checked", true);
        $.each(boxes, function() {
            //let id = jQuery(this); //getting info
            //let id = (data.node.id); //not working
            let id = $(this).data('id'); //not working
            boxes_id.push(id);
        }); 
        return boxes_id;
    }
});
```

I can simply get this (but it returns not what I need I can just verify that I have the right element in `this`):

```
let id = $(this).attr('id');
```

But I can't get this (it returns null)

```
let id = $(this).data('id');
```

I tried to just alert everything I know about the element:

```
let id = jQuery(this)
```

and I can see there is a plenty of data attributes but I can't get any of them... Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally found a sollution! It's actually simple! You have to access these `data` with `.map()`!

Like this:

```
$(".js-save-product").on('click', function(){
    let boxes = check_checkboxes();
    alert(JSON.stringify(boxes));

});

function check_checkboxes(){
    let boxes_id = [];
    let boxes = $('.js-categories-checkboxtree').jstree('get_checked', true)
    $.each(boxes, function() {
        let id = $(this).map(function() { return this.data.id }).get().join();
        boxes_id.push(id);
    }); 
    return boxes_id;
}
```